# ionic 3 with storage

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 with storage.

First, i import storage in the app.module.ts

```
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

imports: [
IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
]
```

I developed Ecommerce app.If I add to any product to cart using storage.

Here is my code for Cart page.

```
   <ion-row class="apply-coupon" *ngFor="let p of Cartproducts;let i=index">
<ion-col col-4>
<img src="{{p.P_IMAGES[0].URL}}" alt="product2">
</ion-col>
<ion-col col-8>
<h1>{{p.P_TITLE}}</h1>
<p class="subtitle">Subtitle</p>
<p class="code">Code: 123</p>
<div>
<button (click)="cancel(i)">Cancel X</button>
</div>
</ion-col>  
</ion-row>

 this.items.push(item);
 this.storage.set('products',this.items);
```

item is a product detail.and I have displayed the cart count.

```
this.storage.get('products').then((data) => {
     if(data != null)
     {
       this.Cartproducts=data;
       console.log(this.Cartproducts);

     }
    });
```

here is my consoled value.

```
   [
    {
        'Product_title':'Product name',
        'Product desc':'product dec',
        'id':1
    },
    {
        'Product_title':'Product name',
        'Product desc':'product dec'
        'id':2
    }
]
```

If I need to remove the last product.

```
 this.Cartproducts.splice(i, 1);
 console.log(this.Cartproducts);
 this.storage.remove('products');
 this.storage.set('products',this.Cartproducts);
```

Here is my consoled value.

```
[
    {
        'Product_title':'Product name',
        'Product desc':'product dec',
        'id':1
    }
]
```

I remove the storage value in `'products'` Again I set the value `products`

I I need another product.so I am going to the product page and add the product.

But my result is

```
[
    {
        'Product_title':'Product name',
        'Product desc':'product dec',
        'id':1
    },
    {
        'Product_title':'Product name',
        'Product desc':'product dec'
        'id':2
    },
    {
        'Product_title':'Product name',
        'Product desc':'product dec'
        'id':3
    }
]
```

But Actually, I remove the second product.Did not set to storage why?

Kindly advice me,

Thanks

Comment: Clearly, when you are moving to the product page you are not updating your model value in which you are pushing your data .Might be ionic is making cache for app performance

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.I have a list of the product displayed on the product page.also, i don't understand ur questions

Comment: Can you also add the code of add product page?

Comment: @vaibhavmaster.i edit my question.kindly check it.

Comment: Well the code is still not complete because i cant track the "item" variable but the issue is around "this.items.push(item);
 this.storage.set('products',this.items);"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
    this.storage.get('products').then((data) => {
     if(data == null)
     {
      data=[];
     }
this.items=data;//re-initialize the items array equal to storage value
this.items.push(item);
 this.storage.set('products',this.items);
    });
```

instead of

```
this.items.push(item); this.storage.set('products',this.items)
```

Comment: Thanks for ur patient.I have one doubt.My question is item is already array value and the length is 3.why again i push to array?

Comment: Thank you.My Issue is fixed.But I got another issue.If add any product to cart.Sometimes values are undefined why?

Comment: Did the above answer help?

Comment: ok, then use console.log(item) to check that you are always pushing the item which is defined. And remember we are using a callback for pushing the item.